# javascript double assignment

Tags: javascript

Question: What is the value of foo.x?

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
foo.x
# undefined
```

Here are my thoughts:
    double assignment, right to left

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo = {n: 2};
foo.x = foo

foo.x
# Object {n: 2, x: Object}
```

Which concept should I review? Thanks!

Comment: You're setting foo.x, to foo, which you then set to { n:2 }. 

So foo no longer has an x key. Only an n key (or another way to think of it, foo never did have an x, because {n:2} never had x). You replaced foo altogether.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
foo.x`

So here you're setting `foo.x` to `foo` but also setting `foo` to `{n:2}`

So after that, `foo` would equal `{n:2}`

So `foo.x` no longer exists.

The reason the second one works, is because you're saying `foo.x` equals `foo` which equals `{n:2, x: object}`

Answer (score 0):

what `foo.x=foo={n:2}` does is actually `bar.x=foo={n:2}`.

`foo={n:2}` changes foo to point to a new and different object so the `foo.x=` becomes `bar.x=`.

Comment: BTW, the code you show is a perfect example for undesirable side effect. When you say `foo.x=<blah>` you expect the change is going to be laid on `foo.x` but not `foo` itself. However, the `<blah>` has a side effect on `foo` that's where all the confusion comes from.

Answer (score 0):

One helpful concept is [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

As you can see, assignment operations (i.e. `=`) have a lower precedence than member access (i.e. `foo.x`). So `foo.x` is evaluated before `foo = {n: 2}`, and later its own assignment. So the `foo.x` that is assigned refers to the old `foo`, rather than the one that is just assigned.